# Filter an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to change an object key with another, depending by condition.

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'carl',
  age: 2
};

const filterF = (obj, toChange, newV) => {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => {
    if (obj[key] === toChange) {
      acc[key] = newV;
    }
    return acc
  }, {})
}


console.log(filterF(obj, 'name', 'newName'))
```

Basically i expect this:

```
{
  name: 'newName',
  age: 2
};
```

Running my code i get an empty object. How to fix the code?

Comment: Your code does not do anything with properties that you do not want to change.

Comment: When you debugged this code, what did you learn? It would tell you, for example, that `obj[key]` is `carl`, not `name`.

Comment: `obj[toChange] = newV` is all you need

Comment: @Jamiec, it does not work

Comment: @Asking [Sure it does](https://jsfiddle.net/8aLxsjwr/)

Comment: @Jamiec, i need to use reduce function. Could you help?

Comment: Why do you need to use `reduce`? Thats like saying "I'm driving nails, I need to use a shoe". Why use the wrong tool for the job?

Comment: By the way, your original post says "I want to change an object key ..." but your code then goes on to (attempt to) change a value, not a key. Note that `name` is a key while `carl` is a value.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to add or update the value

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'carl',
  age: 2
};

const addOrUpdate= (obj, key, value) => { 
// no need to iterate
  obj[key] = value;
return obj
}


console.log(addOrUpdate(obj, 'name', 'newName'))
```

If you only need to update the value if its key already exists in object.

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'carl',
  age: 2
};

const update= (obj, key, value) => { 
// no need to iterate
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    obj[key] = value;
   }
return obj
}


console.log(update(obj, 'name', 'newName'))

// no new value added
console.log(update(obj, 'city', 'my city'))
```

If you just want to know how to achieve this with reduce for leaning purpose only.

> you should not use reduce here since you are just creating a shallow
> copy of the previous object, but just for learning purpose i have
> added an example and where you went wrong.

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'carl',
  age: 2
};

const filterF = (obj, toChange, newV) => {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => {
     // you had key wronly written as keys, and comparing objectp[key] value with new key
  if (key === toChange) {
      acc[key] = newV;
    } else {
      acc[key] = obj[key];
    }
    return acc
  }, {})
}


console.log(filterF(obj, 'name', 'newName'))
```

Comment: Or minimally: `obj[key] = value`

Comment: He replied in his question comment that this does not work else I would have written that too "obj[toChange] = newV is all you need – 
Jamiec"

Comment: It does work, he just doesn't know it, and he's changing the requirements to now include "must use reduce".

Answer (score -1):

You should apply the changes by assigning a config to the original object.

This will allow you to change many properties at once.

```js
const
  obj = { name: 'carl', age: 2 },
  alter = (obj, config) => Object.assign(obj, config); // or { ...obj, ...config }

console.log(alter(obj, { name: 'newName' }))
```

If you really want to split-out the key and value as separate params, you could try this instead:

```js
const
  obj = { name: 'carl', age: 2 },
  alter = (obj, key, value) => Object.assign(obj, { [key]: value });

console.log(alter(obj, 'name', 'newName'))
```

Comment: (i did not vote down) but your answer really does not answer his question. He is confused about using reduce to update keys value and also creating a new object rather than updating value